# How do I find the residuals of this problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, laurent-series

> Find all the singularities in the finite plane and the corresponding residues. Show the details.

$$\frac{8}{1+z^2}$$

I am a bit stuck on this problem:

So I know the residual is going to be the coefficient associated with the first negative exponent in the Laurent series. Why do I have to find both the singularities and the residual? They seem like different questions no?

So the singularities are at $z = i$ because $i^2 = -i$ and that's when the denominator will equal 0.

But how do I find the residuals? So I remember that:

$$\frac{1}{1+z} = 1 - z + z^2 - ...$$

So I now multiply each element by 8:

$$\frac{8}{1+z} = 8(1 - z + z^2 - ...)t$$

But none of these terms have an exponent of -1 so I cannot find the coefficient...

Sigh, what am. I doing wrong?

Next problem, same as above but different function: $$\frac{1}{1-e^z}$$

Comment: The reside is nonzero only at the singularities, so you have to start by finding the singularities.

Comment: You found $i$: what about $-i$?

Comment: You have to find the Laurent series about each singularity.  Find the Taylor series about $z=0$ doesn't help.

Comment: When you typed $i^2=-i$, did you mean $i^2=-1$?

Comment: Note:  $\dfrac8{1+z^2}=\dfrac{4i}{z+i}-\dfrac{4i}{z-i}$

Comment: Buit then how does this give us the residue?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the following:
$$\frac{8}{1+z^2}=\frac{8}{(z-i)(z+i)}$$
So we have two simple poles, one at $z=i$ and another at $z=-i$. We can then use the following:
$$\text{Res}(f,c)=\lim_{z\rightarrow c}(z-c)f(z)$$
Which gives:
$$\text{Res}(f,i)=\lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{8}{z+i}=-4i$$
Similarly we obtain:
$$\text{Res}(f,-i)=4i$$
For $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-e^z}$ we rewrite $e^z$ using eulers formula and obtain:
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{1-e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))}$$
Clearly we have simple poles when $z=2\pi in$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and everywhere else the function is well behaved. Taking the limit as before we find:
$$\text{Res}(f,2\pi i n)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 2\pi in}\frac{x+iy-2\pi in}{1-e^x(\cos(y)-i\sin(y)}$$
Setting $x=0$ we obtain:
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 2\pi n}\frac{iy-2\pi i n}{1-\cos(y)-i\sin(y)}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 2\pi n}\frac{i}{\sin(y)-i\cos(y)}=-1$$
Thus we have that $f(z)$ has simple poles at $z=2\pi i n$ with residues of $-1$.

Note: For higher order poles, you must either look at the laurent series expansion or use the following formula for an $n$th order pole:
$$\text{Res}(f,c)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\rightarrow c}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}[(z-c)^nf(z)]$$

Comment: What's the notation $Res(f,c)$? You're just saying that the residue is a function of a function and a point c = the singularity right?

Comment: Sorry are your signs right? When we approach i, isn't the residual 4i and not -4i?

Comment: Where didd the i go in $2 \pi i n $ in the numerator? @chris

Comment: How do we just wind up with i in the numerator? @Christopher Quinn La Fond Jr.

Comment: I found this: https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/find-all-the-singularities-in-the-finite-plane-and-the-6/

Comment: You are correct. I dropped a sign and the $i$ it was simply a typo. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)=\frac{8}{z^2+1}$ has simple poles at $z=\pm i$
$$\text{Res}(f(z),i)=\underset{z\to i}{\text{lim}}\frac{8 (z-i)}{(z-1) (z+i)}=\frac{8}{2i}=-4i$$
in a similar way can be proved that
$$\text{Res}(f(z),-i)=4i$$

---

Forgot the second question
$$\frac{z}{1-e^z}=-1+\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^2}{12}+O\left(z^3\right)$$
the dividing by $z$ we get
$$g(z)=\frac{1}{1-e^z}=-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{z}{12}+O\left(z^2\right)$$
Therefore
$$\text{Res}(g(z),0)=-1$$

Comment: Are your signs right? Isn't 8/2i = 4i?

Comment: Can you elaborate your expansion in the second question?

Comment: I am confused about something... the tone is more of confusion. I should say: "why is 8/2i = -4i" and not 4i? @Raffaele

Comment: Oh I see... you multiply top and bottom by i so: $\frac{8}{2i} = \frac{8i}{-2}$ since $i^2 = -1$ and then $\frac{8}{2i} = -4i$